# Wordpress changes are visible only to logged in users

Tags: php, wordpress

So here is an unbelievable issue , i am working on wordpress but the problem is if i changes the content in the template file the changes are visible only if the user is logged in . no condition in the template .

for try i have created a template check.php and put the content only

```
<? echo "hieeee" ; ?>
```

assigned this to a page , first time it shows me the correct content for both conditions, but if i change the content like

```
<? echo "hieeee this is update " ; ?>
```

for logged in user it will show **hieeee this is update** and for logged out users **hieeee** can't understand where is the issue .

PHP Version 5.5.16 | mysql client 5.0.11 | SunOS wp1.superhome.com.au 5.11

Comment: Could you share your hosting setup with us? There might be some caching happening for non-session/cookie views or something.

Comment: c panel credentials ???

Comment: No, don't give your passwords away @ris. What he wants to know is the type of OS, PHP version, SQL version, etc.

Comment: Check your plugins for caching rules like "Do not cache for logged in users", etc. Also try to break the cache with a query string in the url (i.e. example.com/?foo=bar), Ctrl + F5, clear browser caches, etc. Once you've done that and the problem persists, come back and update your question.

Comment: And whether you're on a shared host or a VPS/dedi. Some shared hosts might setup custom caching services that interfere with your systems.

Comment: no effect with CTRL+F5 @gillytech

Comment: Any caching plugins @ris? Update with the stack info being asked in the other comments

Comment: here is some server information http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e24jdqq7f

Comment: @gillytech no caching plugin .

Comment: here is the php info https://superhome.com.au/phpinfo.php

Comment: Does the latest version show correctly iin another browser? (Where you haven't browsed the page before?) It definility seems like a caching issue.

Comment: PHP Version 5.5.16 | mysql client 5.0.11 | SunOS wp1.superhome.com.au 5.11  (Now QUICK delete that phpinfo file, you're asking to get hacked! @ris)

Comment: yes i have checked in the private browsing in Firefox and also tried in the fresh browsers

Comment: Have you tried the same on your local computer?

Comment: @riz man this is a GOOD question. It's obvious you have caching off. What does deactivating/reactivating your theme do? Out of curiosity

Comment: but if there is caching problem this should for both logged in and logged-out users.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld yes working perfectly on local.

Comment: Caching usually do not apply (as default) when you're logged into the admin area of Wordpress. It seems like a caching-plugin but you say it's not - so I'll take your word for it :-)

Comment: Are you using exactly the same plugins locally as on the production server?

Comment: yes exactly the same database , same word-press folder. everything same

Comment: Do you mind listing which plugins you are using?

Comment: bbPress, Captcha,Contact Form 7,Denon Studio Paypal Pro Gateway, Google Analytics, Google XML Sitemaps, Gravity Forms, Gravity PDF, Meta Slider, Newsletter, Nginx Helper, Really Simple CAPTCHA, Regenerate Thumbnails, UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore, WooCommerce, WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing, WooCommerce PDF Invoice, WooCommerce Product Add-ons, WooThemes Helper, WordPress Database Backup, WordPress SEO Premium, YouTube for WordPress

Comment: its solve there was a plugin Nginx Helper which stores the cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its solved There was a plugin **Nginx Helper** which store the cache on server. Thanx all for your efforts

Answer (score 1):

This is definility a caching issue. First I thought it was a caching plugin, but it seems like you have full control of that. It worked locally but not on production server, so it had to be something on the server.

Taking a closer look at the [phpinfo()](https://superhome.com.au/phpinfo.php) you've supplied, superhome host is using **Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev**

You could try to disable the cache temporarily by doing:

- If PHP runs as an Apache module, use .htaccess file: `php_flag opcache.enable Off`
- If PHP runs as CGI/FastCGI, use .user.ini file: `opcache.enable=0`
- If you have access to php.ini, try to disable it that there.

**UPDATE**

It seemed you find the actual answer that there was a plugin messing it up, but if someone else stumples upon the same issue this answer might help.